# PHP: How to receive JSON array from iPad app

Tags: php, json, ipad

Disclaimer: I am fairly new to using json.

I am trying to use php to receive json data from an iPAd application. I know how to convert json to an array in php, but how do I actually receive it and store it into a variable so it can be decoded?

Here are a couple examples that I have tried based on google and stackoverflow searches.

```
$json_request = @file_get_contents('php://input'); 
$array = json_decode($json_request);

AND ALSO

$array = json_decode($_POST['data'], true);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the basic idea already.

you should test that the value is set and also strip extra slashes from the incoming string before trying to parse it as JSON.

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){
  $array = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']),true);
  //$array now holds an associative array
}//Data Exists
```

It also would not be a bad idea before you start working with the array to test that the call to `json_decode()` was successful by ensuring that `$array` isn't `null` before use.

If you do not fully trust the integrity of the information being sent you should do extended checking along the way instead of trusting that a given key exists.

```
if($array){ // Or (!is_null($array)) Or (is_array($array)) could be used
  //Process individual information here

  //Without trust
  if(isset($array['Firstname'])){
    $CustomerId = $array['Firstname'];
  }//Firstname exists
}//$array is valid
```

I in-particular like to verify information when I am building queries dynamically for information that may not be required for a successful db insert.

In the above example `$_POST['data']` indicates that what ever called the PHP script did so passing the JSON string using the `post` method in a variable identified as `data`.

You could check more generically to allow flexibility in the sending method by using the `$_REQUEST` variable, or if you know it is coming as via the `get` method you can check `$_GET`. `$_REQUEST` holds all incoming parameters from both `get` and `post`.

If you don't know what the name of the variable coming in is and want to play really fast and loose you could loop over the keys in `$_REQUEST` trying to decode each one and use the one that successfully decoded (if any). *[Note: I'm not encouraging this]*

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. One quick question tho, will the json always come in as 'data'? (To receive any json do I use $_POST['data']?) Or is there a specific name/variable I need to be aware of?

Comment: that is determined entirely by the way the information is being sent to the server.

Comment: That makes sense. Once again thank you for the quick response.